# Do you have to specify the resolution of images for the Native tab bar with TriggerIO

Tags: trigger.io, forge

TriggerIO supports the native tab bar and it looks really easy to add buttons but does it support retina graphics for the icons? Or is this needed? (specifying the nicer image scales down? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single, larger image is the best option - we do scale them down to fit properly inside the button itself.

As a rule of thumb, the icon should be > 100 pixels high to stay crisp on retina displays.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using icons that are 100x100 and 200x200, and they all look fuzzy and pixelated on iPhones with Retina display. Looks like they are resized for non-retina devices only.